# How to find data from nested array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: { type: String },
  code: { type: String },
  region: [{
    name: { type: String },
    city: [{
      name: { type: String },
      latitude: { type: String },
      longitude: { type: String },
    }],
  }],
})
```

I need to get list of region -> city -> name (list of sities names)
In the begining I tried a query to get list of (Array)city

```
const list = await Model.findOne(
  { $and: [{ code: req.params.code }, { 'region.name': 'Harjumaa' }] },
  { 'region.city.name': 1 },
)
```

And receive this data:

[image]

Then I search list of regions I send query:

```
Model.findOne({ code: req.params.code }, { region: 1 })
```

And receive data like this:

[image]

I want to get list of cities names in the same format.

My data sample:

```
{
  "country": "Estonia",
  "code": "ee",
  "region": [
    {
      "name": "Harjumaa",
      "city": [
        {
          "name": "Aegviidu vald",
          "latitude": "59.27941132",
          "longitude": "25.62571907"
        },
        {
          "name": "Anija vald",
          "latitude": "59.27643967",
          "longitude": "25.48167992"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample data

Comment: @AshayMandwarya Add to body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$project` with `$region.city.name` path will give you an array of arrays since you have two levels of nesting. To fix that you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) which will flatten your final result into single array, try:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { code: "ee" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            cityNames: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$region.city.name",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```